# Transcendental equations solution using perturbation expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, perturbation-theory, approximations

How to solve an equation of the following form:
$$ e^{ik} = -1 + ik\epsilon $$
where, $\epsilon$ is a small number.
As $\epsilon$ goes to zero, the value of $k$ goes to $\pi$ (choosing only the lowest positive value). How to expand it around $\pi$ in powers of $\epsilon$ so as to get a value of $k$ as a solution depending upon $\epsilon$?

Answer (score 0):

In order to expand near $k=\pi$ you can substitute $k = \pi + q$ and expand in $q$ near $q=0$.

A more general approach would be to separate the real and the imaginary parts of this equation by using $k = k' + ik''$ and solve for each of them separately:
$$e^{ik} = e^{i(k'+ik''}) = e^{ik'}e^{-k''}= \cos(k')e^{-k''} +i\sin(k')e^{-k''} = -1 + i(k'+ik'')\epsilon = -1 +ik' -k'',$$
separating the real and the imaginary parts we obtain
$$\cos(k')e^{-k''} = -1 -k'',\\
\sin(k')e^{-k''} = k'.$$

One could now plot the two curves in order to see where they intersect, in order to see what the solution looks like.

Comment: I did it using separating real and imaginary parts. real part always give $k= \pi$ and imaginary part gave me $k =\pi -\frac{\pi \epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$. But they are not equal!. Shouldn't the answer be a complex k value?

Comment: You assume that $k$ is real, whereas I propose in my answer to assume that it has a real and an imaginary parts.

Comment: I didn't get it! can you elaborate a bit? It seems that i am stuck

Comment: Your approach doesn't has $\epsilon$ in it. There should be an expansion in terms of $\epsilon$ because that is the small parameter which controls the value of k

Comment: Indeed, there's an error in my calculation ;)

Comment: @https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/2451/qmechanic Can you shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so i have managed to obtain something. This is how it goes: 
Take the following equation 
$e^{2ik} = -1 + 2ik\epsilon $ 
As we know that $k$ goes to $\pi$/2 as $\epsilon$ goes to zero, so we expand around $\pi$/2.We write 
 $e^{2i(\pi/2+ k(\epsilon))} = -1 + 2i\epsilon(\pi/2+ k(\epsilon))$ 
The left hand side becomes: $ -1(1+ 2ik(\epsilon))$. 
 Equating the imaginary parts, we get , 
 $k(\epsilon) = -(\pi/2 + k(\epsilon))\epsilon $ 
 Solving for $k(\epsilon)$ gives 
 $ k(\epsilon) = -((\pi/2)\epsilon)/(1+ \epsilon) $. 
 We can expand this as: 
 $ k(\epsilon) = -\pi/2(\epsilon - (\epsilon)^2 + ... )$. 
 In this way i do get, indeed the real part of k, but i do not get the imaginary part. If i go to the second order, then i do see imaginary values as well. But, it remains to be seen at what point one should stop i.e upto which order the expansion should be taken.